# LaTeX displays (replaces? shows?) combining comma above right (U+315) as a backtick/grave accent (U+0060)

Tags: symbols, unicode, characters, letters, diacritical-mark

I am using Overleaf to write a grammar of Lushootseed (a native language) and I need to use the symbol ƛ̕, which is composed of ƛ and ̕ (a combining diacritic). I've been able to get other characters I need to display properly (such as š, ə, and ƛ), using these methods:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\SelectInputMappings{ % To define š and č
  scaron={š},
  ccaron={č},
}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0259}{\textschwa} % To define schwa (ə)
```

I've used these tools to get the other characters I need to work, and have inserted this to try to add ̕:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0315}{\char"0315}
```

But no matter how I try to get ̕ to display, it always disappears or shows up as `, a backtick:

`` ʔəsƛ`ubil čəd `` instead of `ʔəsƛ̕ubil čəd`

How do I fix this? If I try to get it to render `` ʔəsƛ`ubil čəd `` intentionally, it spits out `ʔəsƛ‘ubil čəd` (with ANOTHER different character!). Also, Overleaf is saying "Bad character code (789)" (789 is the number of ̕) on the line where I try to use it.

I don't know much about LaTeX but I feel like this should work. What am I doing wrong? I will also need the combining diacritic

Comment: you are using pdftex so you can not have char hex 0315, fonts have at most 256 characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

classic tex is an 8 bit system so fonts have at most 256 characters, you can display Unicode characters by using `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` to map the slot to something TeX can handle eg map a greek alpha to an `a` in LGR (Greek) encoding that has the Greek alphabet in the ascii slots.

But it is easier to use a Unicode TeX such as lualatex, and a font that has the characters, this works on overleaf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\begin{document}


I am using Overleaf to write a grammar of Lushootseed
(a native language) and I need to use the symbol ƛ̕, which is
composed of ƛ and ̕ (a combining diacritic).
I've been able to get other
 characters I need to display properly
(such as š, ə, and ƛ), using these methods:

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just select **lualatex** as the compiler in the left sidebar menu.